# Google Calendar producing different result between importing from Android App vs Web and Iphone

Tags: android, calendar, icalendar

I'm wondering if there's anything wrong specified within the .ics file I generated, it's a follow up to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51131399/wrong-time-when-importing-ics-event) in which the solution has been implemented but in this particular case either I found an App's bug or something not being implemented correctly from our side.

Given .ics file with content as below

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID;X-RICAL-TZSOURCE=TZINFO:-//\, Inc.//NONSGML website.co
 m//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID;X-RICAL-TZSOURCE=TZINFO:America/Los_Angeles
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:20181104T020000
RDATE:20181104T020000
RDATE:20191103T020000
TZOFFSETFROM:-0700
TZOFFSETTO:-0800
TZNAME:PST
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:20190310T020000
RDATE:20190310T020000
RDATE:20200308T020000
TZOFFSETFROM:-0800
TZOFFSETTO:-0700
TZNAME:PDT
END:DAYLIGHT
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
CREATED;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20190221T110121Z
DTEND;TZID=America/Los_Angeles;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20190308T100000
DTSTART;TZID=America/Los_Angeles;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20190308T090000
DTSTAMP;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20190221T110121Z
ATTENDEE#<Client 1122742 "test1 account">
UID:6bOpCpTxArFlX3jvFD7NNLuROX@website.com
DESCRIPTION:One Hour Appointment
URL:https://app.local.website.com/appts/UQ4hwz3RJw
SUMMARY:Appointment with BUG_LOCAL
ORGANIZER;CN=Hakim Ahmad;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED:mailto:notif
 ications+development@email.website.com
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20250316T070000Z
SEQUENCE:0
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

In this test, with single google account, if I import the file from Web interface as in per [Import events into Google Calendar](https://www.google.com/appserve/mkt/p/AHANi0YPa_dtBHDKrkFaaDF8hmIG_J1PjjhLTukc6xkZqM1pa_J-_QToVii9tVtZnRI5t11QvQPYc2g_aA-aWzH-fhgOqKsH1tNuyT38C8rnt36AmNkiqCBzBIq14VQ8sxn4629nxLEgjBkfNQhD). I will get result as following for:

PST-8:
[screenshot for PST-8 from web import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmYuj.png)

```
started on 8th March 2019, 9am
PST -> PDT switch on 10 March 2019, 2am*
started on 15th March 2019, 9am
started on 22th March 2019, 9am
etc..
```

GMT+8:
[screenshot for GMT+8 from web import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSfH3.png)

```
started on 9th March 2019, 1am
PST -> PDT switch on 10 March 2019, 6pm*
started on 16th March 2019, 12am
started on 23th March 2019, 12am
etc..
```

In contrary to result generated from android import as following for:

PST-8:
[screenshot for PST-8 from android import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nRAF.png)

```
started on 8th March 2019, 9am
PST -> PDT switch on 10 March 2019, 2am*
started on 15th March 2019, 10am
started on 22th March 2019, 10am
etc..
```

GMT+8:
[screenshot for GMT+8 from android import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzuaZ.png)

```
started on 9th March 2019, 1am
PST -> PDT switch on 10 March 2019, 6pm*
started on 16th March 2019, 1am
started on 23th March 2019, 1am
etc..
```

Also tested with Mac Calendar and iOS Calendar which produce result the same as the web imported one.

This is tested from multiple android devices, so the 'bug' consistent across  android Google Calendar app.

Also checked if the timezone upon importing play any role which it doesn't.

Is there anything I can do about this? Had already contact to Google through multiple channel but cannot get any response.

some references:
[* PST-8, GMT+8 comparison of time switch on 10th of March 2019](https://www.worldtimebuddy.com/?qm=1&lid=8,8,2643743,128&h=8&date=2019-3-10&sln=1-3)

Additional References For Answer's Follow up:

similar .ics translated to zulu time:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID;X-RICAL-TZSOURCE=TZINFO:-//\, Inc.//NONSGML website.com//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
CREATED;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20190221T110121Z
DTEND;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20190308T180000Z
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20190308T170000Z
DTSTAMP;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20190221T110121Z
ATTENDEE#<Client 1122742 "test1 account">
UID:6bOpCpTxArFlX3jvFD7NNLuROX@website.com
DESCRIPTION:One Hour Appointment
URL:https://app.local.website.com/appts/UQ4hwz3RJw
SUMMARY:Appointment with BUG_LOCAL
ORGANIZER;CN=Hakim Ahmad;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED:mailto:notifications+development@email.website.com
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20250316T070000Z
SEQUENCE:0
LOCATION:Los Angeles
PRIORITY:5
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are facing the same problems as I did, too.

If you cut the timezone crap and note everything in Zulu-time, it works. At least it did for me.

DTSTART:20190226T123456**Z**

I've posted my solution here: [How to generate an iCalender entry that works on Outlook, Android and iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54876217/how-to-generate-an-icalendar-entry-that-works-on-outlook-android-and-ios)

Comment: I modify the .ics file accordingly by removing the `VTIMEZONE` block and use the zulu time and format it accordingly. it's still produce output same as before

Comment: Have you calculated your target time in UTC before? I mean, if you want to have 08:30 hours in CET (central euroean time) today, you need to code this as 20190307T073000Z.

Comment: yeah I did. I put in the ics text modified from the previous one for reference in the question.

Comment: Can you please attach that new ics file.

Comment: yeah, I paste the full text of the ics file at the bottom of the question.

Comment: I copied this ics example into a file and opened it with outlook 2013.
It appears as "Occurs every Friday effective 2019-03-08 until 2025-03-14 from 18:00 to 19:00". Consider, that I am living in Europe with CET timezone. Comparing the file to the assumed times, this seems accurate to me.